# Unix (Gnu/Linux, Mac OS X) program or command to count HTTP connections made by a program

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, unix

I have got a testing suite for an applications that performs lots of HTTP requests.

This number changes each time you run the tests. Is there a Unix command or program that "listens" to another program counting its http requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any packet sniffer will do that for you. Check out [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or  [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). You'll have to setup a few filters on the data they collect, but that's easy.

Comment: how would you tell which requests are coming from the application being tested?

Comment: Do you know the destination address you're testing? you can probably tell which port your testing application is using. Filter by these criteria also

Comment: Yup I know the address. Tests always do POST requests to a unique URL

Comment: wireshark worked fine. Now I know that my test suite performs and checks quite 200 XML-RPC calls :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- You can trace your application's system calls with `truss`/`trace`/`strace`/... (the name, command line syntax and output format is OS-dependent), and watch for `connect` calls. If your application also uses non-HTTP networking you may have to work a little harder to filter the relevant connections.
- You can use `LD_PRELOAD` or a debugger to modify the function that creates the HTTP connections. But this may be too intrusive for a test.
- You can put a simple proxy between your application and the web. Both perl and python come with libraries that would make it a 10–20-line program. This is the approach I'd prefer unless you're specifically testing your application's behavior against a specific server or proxy.